# Ionic native geolocation catch errors on watchposition

Tags: geolocation, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm using geolocation in my Ionic app, and I would like to use the method watchposition to check whenever (for example) the user turns off GPS while watching his position to catch the error and show a message on screen.
Following [this guide](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/) I'm doing this:

```
let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
  watch.subscribe((data)=>{

  })
```

but I can't find a method to catch errors while being subscribed to data. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to catch errors thrown from your `watchPosition()`.

According to the [API docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/#watchPosition) it returns `Observable<Position>`. This means you can use the standard way of setting an error handler in your `subscribe` function. It can take 3 parameters. `subscribe(onsuccess,onerror,oncompletion)`.

```
let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
  watch.subscribe((data)=>{

  },error => {
      console.log(error); //error handling
  })
```